# Loading pictures in "background-image" css property fails with "kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1" on iOS using WKWebView

Tags: cordova, wkwebview, cordova-ios

We recently started implementing wkWebView in our Cordova app, using cordova-ios@5.1.1 platform.
In our app, we load some pictures and show them in a div using "background-image" property.
Pictures are downloaded at runtime and are stored in a path like the following:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/78A8D94E-A467-454B-95C4-FF4C121E3CCD/Library/files/some/path/to/file
```

Everything worked fine in UIWebView.
Using wkWebView, images are failing t load, giving out this error: "kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1".
We already tried removing the "file://" part but to no avail.

These are our installed plugins:

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.2.1 "PhotoViewer"
com.centrosistemi.plugin.Pdf 0.1.5 "PDF"
cordova-custom-config 5.1.0 "cordova-custom-config"
cordova-open-native-settings 1.5.2 "Native settings"
cordova-pdf-generator 2.0.8 "PDFGenerator"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.3.0 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-email 1.2.7 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.2.0 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-filepicker 1.1.6 "File Picker"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.1.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
cordova-plugin-migrate-localstorage 0.0.2 "Migrate WebView Data"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.0 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr 2.1.1 "Cordova WKWebView File XHR Plugin"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.4 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
cordova-support-google-services 1.3.2 "cordova-support-google-services"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.12 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
phonegap-nfc 1.0.4 "NFC"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.0.1 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.3.0 "PushPlugin"
```

I'm not sure it is related, but the error seems loke a "Host not found error" as stated here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors/cfhosterrorhostnotfound

As far as i understand, ionic's webview plugin serves content using some sort of webserver at "http://localhost:8080", and seems to be working, but that plugin requires iOS11+ and we need to support iOS10 as well.

Are we missing something?

Thanks in advance!